# Configuring username and password for local mongodb installation

Tags: java, mongodb

I have installed mongob as a service locally, along with mongo compass. I have a legacy java code which has connection code as:

```
this.username = "....";
this.password = "....";
this.database = "testdb";
this.host = "localhost";
this.portNum = 27017;
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(username, database, password.toCharArray());

mongo = MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                    .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(host, portNum))))
                    .credential(credential)
                    .build());
```

During local installation, I didn't see any option for username/password configuration, but code needs it.

How to get these details configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create user using `db.createUser`. At that time, you need to provide `username, password` which can be used in the code.

[Snippet from doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#create-user-with-roles)

```
use products //database 
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "accountUser", //username
     pwd: "password" //password 
     roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ] //roles
   }
)
```

Comment: Where do I need to run this script?

Comment: You can do this after the installation, at any time. It is user creation for a database with roles. You can use that user to grant/restrict permissions on the database.

Comment: I mean using which tool I can run this. I have compass installed. Is that right place to execute it?

Comment: Yes, You can do via compass.